# C# Wrapper Class for C library

Tags: c#, linux, raspberry-pi, wiringpi

I want to create a C# wrapper class with the functions in [mcp23017.c](https://github.com/hamishcunningham/wiringpi/blob/master/wiringPi/mcp23017.c) within the [WiringPi](https://github.com/hamishcunningham/wiringpi/tree/master/wiringPi) C library. I took this existing C# WiringPi [WrapperClass](https://github.com/danriches/WiringPi.Net/blob/master/WiringPi/WrapperClass.cs) for the other functions. I want to extend this wrapper class to use the functions for mcp23017. I tried creating a new class with one function within the wrapper:

```
public class mcp23017
{

    [DllImport("libmcp23017.so", EntryPoint = "myPinMode")]
    public static extern void myPinMode(struct wiringPiNodeStruct *node,Int32 pin, Int32 mode);

}
```

But I get these errors for the struct element.

```
) expected.
; expected.
{ expected.
} expected.
Invalid token "*" in class struct or interface member declaration
```

Do I have to define a struct in the wrapper class? How does it work? Not familiar with this as I am new to using C#.

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid to use `struct` on a parameter in C#. The marshaller should take care of this behavior for you. Perhaps you meant something like this.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WiringNode
{
    //Struct members here
}

[DllImport("libmcp23017.so", EntryPoint = "myPinMode")]
public static extern void myPinMode(ref WiringNode node, Int32 pin, Int32 mode);
```

Then called as:

```
var myStruct = new WiringStruct();
//Set struct members

myPinMode(ref myStruct, whatever, whatever);
```

Comment: But I want to use the `struct wiringPiNodeStruct` defined in the C library in file wiringPi.h (link: WiringPI). Can I refer the struct in the Wrapper class?

Comment: Not directly. You'll need to recreate the struct on the .net side and then let marshalling handle converting the memory between .net and c

Comment: Okay. Any examples or references on how that can be done? Or any other way to use the functions from C library without creating a wrapper class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923871/pinvoke-struct-translation-from-c would get you started. Basically you'll want to search pinvoke struct to determine how each member should be declared.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Will try and get back.